# Nginx allow subdirectories in single location block

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I've directory say mobile

```
/var/www/mobile
```

That directory has multiple subdirectories like `/android` `/ios` and those directories have multiple PHP files

I'd like to run those PHP files like this

`https://www.example.com/mobile/android/index.php`

`https://www.example.com/mobile/android/products.php`

`https://www.example.com/mobile/ios/products.php`

`https://www.example.com/mobile/ios/feeds.php`

I want to allow these files in a single location block as many directories may be created in the future and don't want to specify separate location blocks for each directory.

I've added a location block in the config file however it is showing a 404 page.

```
location ~* ^/mobile($|/) {
root /var/www;
 try_files $uri $uri/ /mobile/?q=$uri&$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
    #include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9002;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

Help me with this.
Thank you

Comment: Where are you stuck and what have you tried? All you should need to do is create one nginx config where you set `/var/www` as document root. Then you should be able to fetch what ever files you need in the way you ask for.

Comment: yes, it should fetch all files from the root directory but showing 404

Comment: Have you set an `index` directive? What file should process `/mobile/?q=$uri&$args`?